# Python list processing to extract substrings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I parsed an HTML page via beautifulsoup, extracting all `div` elements with specific `class` names into a list.

I now have to clean out HTML strings from this list, leaving behind string tokens I need.

The list I start with looks like this:

```
[<div class="info-1">\nName1a    <span class="bold">Score1a</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-2">\nName1b    <span class="bold">Score1b</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-1">\nName2a    <span class="bold">Score2a</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-2">\nName2b    <span class="bold">Score2b</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-1">\nName3a    <span class="bold">Score3a</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-2">\nName3b    <span class="bold">Score3b</span>\n</div>]
```

The whitespaces are deliberate.
I need to reduce that list to:

```
[('Name1a', 'Score1a'), ('Name1b', 'Score1b'), ('Name2a', 'Score2a'), ('Name2b', 'Score2b'), ('Name3a', 'Score3a'), ('Name3b', 'Score3b')]
```

What's an efficient way to parse out substrings like this?

---

I've tried using the `split` method (e.g. `[item.split('<div class="info-1">\n',1) for item in string_list]`), but splitting just results in a substring that requires further splitting (hence inefficient). Likewise for using `replace`.

I feel I ought to go the other way around and extract the tokens I need, but I can't seem to wrap my head around an elegant way to do this. Being new to this hasn't helped either. I appreicate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not convert BS object to string unless you really need to do that.
2. Use CSS selector to find the `class` that starts with `info`
3. Use `stripped_strings` to get all the non-empty strings under a tag
4. Use `tuple()` to convert an iterable to tuple object

---

```
import bs4

html = '''<div class="info-1">\nName1a    <span class="bold">Score1a</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-2">\nName1b    <span class="bold">Score1b</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-1">\nName2a    <span class="bold">Score2a</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-2">\nName2b    <span class="bold">Score2b</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-1">\nName3a    <span class="bold">Score3a</span>\n</div>, <div class="info-2">\nName3b    <span class="bold">Score3b</span>\n</div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for div in soup.select('div[class^="info"]'):
    t = tuple(text for text in div.stripped_strings)
    print(t)
```

out:

```
('Name1a', 'Score1a')
('Name1b', 'Score1b')
('Name2a', 'Score2a')
('Name2b', 'Score2b')
('Name3a', 'Score3a')
('Name3b', 'Score3b')
```

Comment: This is just great. Thanks a bunch :-)